# Play sound file on Timer end

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a countdown timer and I want an alarm to go off when it reaches the end ... lots for Android and iOS, but nothing that I could find for WP8.

I'm using the DispatcherTimer for counting down.

I'm looking for some information or an example on how to call a sound when the timer finishes counting down.  I have the counter start on a button click and reset on a long press. It all works good, just want a sound effect when it stops after counting down.

```
    private DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    private DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;

    private void BtnCounter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            

        if (this._dispatcherTimer == null)
        {
            this._dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            this._dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            this._dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        }

        if (this.EndTime == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            this.EndTime = DateTime.Now + (TimeSpan)this.tsPicker.Value;
        }

        this._dispatcherTimer.Start();


    }

    void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var remaining = this.EndTime - DateTime.Now;
        int remainingSeconds = (int)remaining.TotalSeconds;
        this.tsPicker.Value = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(remainingSeconds);

        if (remaining.TotalSeconds <= 0)
        {
            this._dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            // Sound code should go here, or a method call to it.
        }
    }

    private void BtnCounter_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        cnt = 0;
        BtnCounter.Content = cnt;
        this._dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        this.EndTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        this.tsPicker.Value = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    }

    protected override void  OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.EndTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
```

Comment: You don't currently have a question.  Nor have you shown any code that you've written to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: more info and example code added

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?  There seems to be a good example using it, titled [Windows Phone 8: Playing Sounds](http://mnjoe.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/windows-phone-8-playing-sounds/)

Comment: Thats playing a sound that you link to.  Is there know way to link to the built in alarm sounds and play those?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/fa895410-7596-46c5-9fa0-b5cffb987a54 (now I know why you found it so difficult to research this stuff - there is NO information about alarm apps!)